# What is difference in the following two programs?

Tags: java

**CODE:1**

```
class Ajay {
    private void display() {
        System.out.println("Ajay");
    }
    public static void main(String ...strings ){
        Ajay r=new Ravi();
        r.display();
    }
}

class Ravi extends Ajay{
    public void display() {
        System.out.println("ravi");
    }
}
```

**CODE:2**

```
class Ravi {
    private void display() {
        System.out.println("ravi");
        }
    }

public class Ajay extends Ravi{
    public void display() {
        System.out.println("ajay");
    }
    public static void main(String ...strings ){
    Ravi r=new Ajay();
        r.display();
    }
}
```

I have a doubt in the above two codes.
CODE 1 executes without any error while CODE 2 throws an error like The method is not visible.
What is the reason for this error??

Comment: Note: Code 2 doesn't "throw an error", it fails to compile with a compile-time error. Errors (and Exceptions) can only be thrown at runtime.

Comment: okk.I was not able to frame the question properly.Why CODE 2 wil not compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your second example you try to call a method `display()` on a variable of type `Ravi`. `Ravi` has no method `display()` that's accessible from this location (i.e. inside `Ajay`).

In your first example, however you call the private `display()` method of `Ajay` from *within* `Ajay`. Note that calling `private` methods does **not** use runtime polymorphism! The exact code to be called is decided at compile-time!

Answer (score 1):

In code 2, your display method in class Ravi is private.

Now you use a reference "r" of Ravi to call display but the method display() is not visible outside the class Ravi.

Even though you have same method display() as public, in Ajay class, but its not overriding the superclass, because you can't reduce the visibility.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is linked to the fact your `display` method in the CODE2 example is `private`, thus you cannot call it.

Answer (score 0):

Offer solution options for the 2nd code:

if you want to display "ravi", then you may declare the display method either like:

```
class Ravi {
    protected void display() {
        System.out.println("ravi");
        }
    }
}
```

or like:

```
class Ravi {
    public void display() {
        System.out.println("ravi");
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to display "ajay", change invocation:

```
Ravi r=new Ajay();
    if(r instanceof Ajay)
        ((Ajay) r).display();
}
```